# Applying bash string operators on a constant string

Tags: string, bash

I'm trying to use bash string operators on a constant string. For instance, you can do the following on variable $foo:

```
$ foo=a:b:c; echo ${foo##*:}
c
```

Now, if the "a:b:c" string is constant, I would like to have a more concise solution like:

```
echo ${"a:b:c"##*:}
```

However, this is not valid bash syntax. Is there any way to perform this?

[The reason I need to do this (rather than hardcoding the result of the substitution, ie. "c" here) is because I have a command template where a "%h" placeholder is replaced by something before running the command; the result of the substitution is seen as a constant by bash.]

Comment: If the strings are delimited with a constant delimiter then why not use `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: Yes, it is also a valid option, I was just curious about how this could be done with bash string operators, which is slightly more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible using parameter expansion.

You could use other commands for this like sed/awk/expr.

but I don't see the requirement for this.
You could just do:

```
tmp=%h
echo ${tmp##*:}
```

Or if speed is not an issue, and you don't want to clutter the current environment with unneeded variables:

```
(tmp=%h; echo ${tmp##*:})
```

Anyway, you'd be better off using the command template to do the string manipulation or using something simple like cut:

```
# get third filed delimited by :
$ cut -d: -f3<<<'a:b:c'
c
```

Or more sophisticated like awk or sed:

```
#get last field separated by ':'
$ awk -F: '{print $NF}'<<<'a:b:c'
c
$ sed 's/.*:\([^:]*\)/\1/'<<<'a:b:c'
c
```

Depends on what you need.

Comment: My main reason to dislike the `cut`-`awk`-`sed`-based solutions is that they are slightly longer, and my reason to dislike the solution with the intermediate variable is that this is for a command template which will be substituted and `exec`'d, forcing me to wrap the command in a `bash -c` invocation if I want to add a variable definition. But well, if there is no way to do what I intended with string operators, I can just use something else. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`expr`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/moreadv.html#EXPRREF) to get a similar result:

```
$ expr match "a:b:c" '.*:\(.*\)'
c
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about this utility.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use Bash regex matching:

```
pattern='.*:([^:]+)$'
[[ "a:b:c" =~ $pattern ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

But why can't you do your template substitution into a variable assignment, then use the variable in the parameter expansion?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason why I'd rather avoid using an intermediate variable assignment if at all possible is because the command is passed to `exec`, so having a variable assignment forces me to wrap this in another shell. Besides, I was curious to know if the intermediate varibale assignment can be avoided.